# Extracting the last four digit of an int 's binary representation

Tags: c

I have a problem of extracting the last 4 numbers of a binary representation
My number is: `1111 1001`
I got the first `4`
However I have the problem to got the last four^:

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 # include <stdlib.h>
 # define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n"
 # define BYTETOBINARY(byte)  \
 (byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
 (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0) 

 int main()
 {
    int num = 505;
    PRINTBIN (num);

    //  int result = num & bitwise;
    //PRINTBIN(result);
    // first num;
    int i;
    int bit=0x01;
    int bitwise;
    for (i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
        int bit1=bit<<i;
        bitwise = bit1|bit;

    }
    printf("1:%d\n", bitwise);
    PRINTBIN(bitwise);

    //second num;
    int bitwise1;
    int b0 = 0;
    int bit2;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
         bit2 = bit<<(4+i);
         bitwise1 = bit2|b0;    
         PRINTBIN(bit2);
    }
    printf("2:%d\n",bitwise1);
    PRINTBIN(bitwise1);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way than what you're doing: `num & 0x0f` will get the last four, then you just print it in binary with `printf("%04b\n", num &0x0f);`. EDIT: the %b specifier is non-standard! probably shouldn't use that then, instead go with the example below. /edit

Any `f` in hexadecimal is `1111` in binary which makes it easy to pull out those quartets. If you can't just use printf, you can also print a bit pretty easily by masking out one at a time, then shifting the number to line up another to display. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%c", (number & 8) ? '1' : '0'); // print the number on the left of the quartet
    number <<= 1; // shift it to the right by one position, putting the next bit in position to print next loop around
}
```

Other useful tricks in bit manipulation are shifting a one around to get a mask. To get bit #n, starting from the right, do `number & (1 << n)`. One shifted left zero times is one - that mask gets you the least significant (right-most) bit. One shifted left one time is two, the second least significant bit, and so on. Your `bit1 = bit << i` line does this, but I prefer to use the literal `1` for this trick to make it clear that it doesn't have to be a variable.

Comment: Oooh, I would think of that as the second four, a better term to use is probably most significant and least significant though. The most significant is the left-most when written, called 'most significant' because they represent the larger numbers. Anyway, the way I'd do it is to shift the number right four times: `num >>= 4;` then repeat the process the same way you did for the first one. By shifting it over you change the new problem into the existing solved problem so you can just do the same thing again.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much. I learned a new technique to make bitwise manipulation easier

Comment: There is no `%b` conversion specifier (at least as far as the C specification or POSIX is concerned).

Comment: @dreamlax oh dear, how did I not realize that! It is a non-standard extension in the compiler I often use. Edited to add a note and an example to get by without that.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to display 4 digits, just use look up table because we already know all the possible representations. 
If you want to display another 4 digits at other position, just do the shifting after `num&0x0F`, but the mask will be other value instead of `0x0F`

```
const char * bin[16] = {
    "0000",
    "0001",
    "0010",
    ......
    "1111"
};

printf("%s\n", bin[num&0x0F]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`num & 0xF` will extract the last for digits.

To print the last 4, code could use:

```
printf("%04d", (num&8)*125 + (num&4)*25 + (num&2)*5 + (num&1));
```

Another approach using octal:
To print the least significant 8, code could use:

```
printf("%08lo", 
   (num&128)*16384LU + (num&64)*4096L + (num&32)*1024L + (num&16)*256 +
   (num&8)*64 + (num&4)*16 + (num&2)*4 + (num&1));
```

This method works with up to at least 21 bits and `unsigned long long` using a many term equation or `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following function extractAllBitsFromIntToArray
Parameters:
int value: the source integer to use for the extraction
int* totalBits: pointer to callers' area to receive size of returned int array
Returns:
int* a pointer to a malloc'd array that contains the extracted bits from 'value'
     least significant bit at offset 0 into the array.
     note: the caller must 'free()' this array when done using it  


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TOTAL_BITS (sizeof(int)<<3) // assumes 8 bit bytes
#define BIT_MASK(count)   (1<<count)

int * extractAllBitsFromIntToArray( int value, int* numBits)
{
    int i = 0; // loop counter
    int *pRetArray = NULL;
    if( NULL == (pRetArray = malloc( TOTAL_BITS*sizeof(int)) ) ) // array to return
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    memset( pRetArray, 0x00, TOTAL_BITS*sizeof(int) ); // clear array

    // extract bits, where pRetArray[0] is LSB
    for( i=0; i<TOTAL_BITS; i++ )
    {
        pRetArray[i] = (value&(BIT_MASK(i)))? 1:
    }

    return( pRetArray );
} // end function: extractAllBitsFromIntToArray
```

Comment: 1) Maybe `#define TOTAL_BITS (sizeof(int)* CHAR_BIT)` and then no assumption needed?  2) Suggest `unsigned value` and `BIT_MASK(count)   (1u << count)` to avoid shifting into the `int` sign bit.  3) Missing something at end of `(value&(BIT_MASK(i)))? 1:`?